# How to implement a task repeatedly while the application is in foreGround

Tags: iphone

I am using location services, in that I get locations list ,and display local notifications to user while my application is in background. Similarly

```
    I want to implement a task repeatedly while the application is running in foreGround. In       appdelegate which method should I use So that I give notifications to the user.
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSThread` is your friend.